# I can't align a button to the background image of the site

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, responsive

My website has an image that covers 100% of width and height, so it means when the screen shrinks or grows, the image does the same, and i have two buttons that must be placed at a certain location of the image (below the image's text) but when the screen resizes, the button doesn't resize equally to be aligned with the image.

i've tried making a flex container with the image and the button, but i couldn't get the expected results, and also it won't let me use % for the position of the button, it remains at the same location, and when using vh, it resizes as well as the background image, but not at the same rate, meaning the buttons would always lose alignment.

the buttons i'm trying to align are the .home-main-buttons which are on the .homepage-button-container which is on the .main-content-wrapper (wrapper used to place the footer correctly)

here's the html code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');

html, body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-content-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
a {
  color: white;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 9vh;
  min-height: 3.5rem;
  z-index: 100;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  background-color: black;
}

.nav-logo {
  position:absolute;
  float:left;
  transform: translateY(-32%);
  width: 9.375rem;
  height:9.375rem;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin:0 30vh; 
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

nav li {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  display: flex;
  float:top;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  height: 9vh;
  width: 100%;
}

  nav a:hover {
    background-color: #FF7415;
}
  nav .has-submenu {
    position: relative;
  }

  nav .has-submenu .sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0; 
    margin-right: 0;
    background-color: black;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  
  nav .has-submenu:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
  }

  nav .has-submenu:hover .sub-menu a {
    background-color: black;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  nav .has-submenu .sub-menu a:hover {
    background-color: #FF7415;
  }

  nav ul li {
    position: relative;
  }

  nav ul li:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
  }

  nav .has-submenu:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0.625rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 0.0625rem 0.0625rem 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.1875rem;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  nav .has-submenu:hover:after {
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  }

.fb-tt-buttons {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  bottom:85%;
  right:2%;
  float:right;
}

.tt-button{
  position: inherit;
  transform: translateX(8%);
}

.banner-img {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.homepage-button-container {
  position: relative;
  bottom:45vh;
  z-index:10;
}

.home-main-buttons {  
  align-items: center;
  margin-inline:2rem;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: #FF7415;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-width: 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.4) 0 2px 4px,rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.3) 0 7px 13px -3px,rgba(255, 116, 21) 0 -3px 0 inset;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: WHITE;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 11.875rem;
  height: 3.75rem;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: box-shadow .15s,transform .15s;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  white-space: nowrap;
  will-change: box-shadow,transform;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.home-main-buttons:focus {
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 116, 21) 0 0 0 1.5px inset, rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.4) 0 2px 4px, rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.3) 0 7px 13px -3px, rgba(255, 116, 21) 0 -3px 0 inset;
}

.home-main-buttons:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(31, 28, 37, 0.4) 0 4px 8px, rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.3) 0 7px 13px -3px, rgba(255, 116, 21) 0 -3px 0 inset;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.home-main-buttons:active {
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 116, 21) 0 3px 7px inset;
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.footer {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
flex-shrink: 0;
margin-top: auto;
height: 100%;
background-color: black;
color: bisque;
font-size: 20px;
}

.footer-logo {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  width:12.5rem;
  height:12.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.footer-info {
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content-wrapper">
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v17.0" nonce="Aw1TIrLL"></script>
  <!-Navigation Bar->
  <nav>
    <img src="img/logo-3.png" class="nav-logo">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Página inicial</a></li>
      <li class="has-submenu">
        <a href="#">Sobre</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Sobre mim</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sobre nós</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="has-submenu">
      <a href="#">Serviços</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Criação de websites</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Limpeza de PC</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="fb-tt-buttons">
      <div class="tt-button"><a href="https://twitter.com/jorge?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-screen-name="false" data-lang="pt" data-dnt="true" data-show-count="false"></a><script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script></div>
      <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100094330637469" data-width="50" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-share=""></div>
  </div>
  </nav>
 
  <!-1024x768 Banner->
  <img src="img/homepage-banner.png" alt="Meu banner" class="banner-img">
  <div class="homepage-button-container">
  <button type="button" class="home-main-buttons" role="button">Ver meu trabalho</button>
  <button type="button" class="home-main-buttons">Começar um projeto</button>
  </div> </div>
  <div class="footer">
  <img src="img/logo-3.png" alt="Minha logo" class="footer-logo">
  <div class="footer-info">
    Yazigi Tech software e manutenção de computadores<br>
    Editor da página: Victor Yazigi<br>
    Designer da página: Sabrina Leonel</div>
</div>
```

i also don't know if it's unlikely to be perfect, because i didn't see many websites that align a button on specific locations of an background image

Comment: IT will be messy one way or another and never really completely responsive. You should change your approach to be clean by not using a `background-image` with text in the first place (also for accessibility reasons) but include text in the DOM itself. Last but not least a SVG would properly be more suitable here.

Comment: it's not exactly a background image because it doesn't cover 100% of the screen, just an specific div, I also made sections for other elements like the footer and the menu, in my design idea, the screen would be like this https://www.canva.com/design/DAFn0ISBtpI/ZSPfwA5bCtS-rhHDXkg_dA/edit?utm_content=DAFn0ISBtpI&utm_campaign=designshare&utm_medium=link2&utm_source=sharebutton with two buttons on the bottom after the last line of text, if I recreate the image's text on css, I would also have to Include the image on the right side of the text, would it be responsively aligned with the text?

Comment: and also, is there a way to convert a PNG image to SVG?

Comment: Yes, here https://www.photopea.com just open the png and save/export as svg